# Getting undefined type of value in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null, nullable, nosuchelementexception

Unable to filter values containing `null`.
I am trying multiple operations on an empty Spark DataSet.

```
case class SourceWithoutFlag( id:String, phone:String, name:String)
case class Target(id:String, phone:String, name:String, start_date:String, end_date:String, flag:String)
```

The code is described below :-

```
var target = spark.emptyDataset[Target]
val source: Dataset[SourceWithoutFlag] = spark
    .read.option("header", true).csv(sourceFile).as[SourceWithoutFlag]
println("New Data Read")
source.show(Int.MaxValue)

var operationRecordCheck = source
    .select("id")
    .withColumnRenamed("id","ids")
operationRecordCheck = target
    .join(operationRecordCheck, target("id") ===
                    operationRecordCheck("ids"),"full_outer")

operationRecordCheck.show
var insertRecordId = operationRecordCheck
    .where(isnull($"id"))
    .select("ids")
insertRecordId.show
```

Here I am reading `source` Dataset which contains these values

```
New Data Read
+---+---------+------+
| id|    phone|  name|
+---+---------+------+
|999|987654321|Jhoney|
|888|876543210|Stuart|
|444|576543210|Brocli|
|555|487654321|Advock|
+---+---------+------+
```

and another Dataset `target` which is an empty Dataset

```
+---+-----+----+----------+--------+----+
| id|phone|name|start_date|end_date|flag|
+---+-----+----+----------+--------+----+
+---+-----+----+----------+--------+----+
```

Now I am performing a join of these two DataSets, getting this result `operationRecordCheck`

```
+----+-----+----+----------+--------+----+---+
|  id|phone|name|start_date|end_date|flag|ids|
+----+-----+----+----------+--------+----+---+
|null| null|null|      null|    null|null|999|
|null| null|null|      null|    null|null|888|
|null| null|null|      null|    null|null|444|
|null| null|null|      null|    null|null|555|
+----+-----+----+----------+--------+----+---+
```

But when I am checking the cell value is null or not it is giving an exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

The cause of the exception is

```
operationRecordCheck
        .where(isnull($"id"))
        .select("ids")
```

I just want to apply the sql query `SELECT ids FROM operationRecordCheck WHERE id IS null;` on the operationRecordCheck Dataset but it is not considering my Dataset Values as `null`.

I have also tried `isnan($"id")` , `$"id".isNull` , `$"id".isNaN` , `$"id".isNotNull` , `$"id" === ""` , `$"id" === null` but it is not giving me the proper result.

Appreciate the help :)

Comment: what  do you want , do you want to join? or filterout null value in particular colmn

Comment: Actually my dataset is showing that it contains null values but when I am filtering the null values from the Dataset, it is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: use .na.fill("")  and generate new dataframe as val df = operationRecordCheck.na.fill("") after it filer data with col("id") === "" or  col("id") =!= "".Simply replace check of null with ""

Comment: yeah tried that but it didn't replaced any.

Comment: your code is working for me. Which imports are you using?

Comment: import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession, types}

Comment: no idea then, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a very similar-looking problem recently (same error message, similar spark-based data manipulation with a join and then later a filter, and the failure traceable to the filter step).
In my case, the failure was averted by adding a Dataset.cache() call just before the filter/'where' call. I think an analogous change in your code would look like this:

```
operationRecordCheck
        .cache()
        .where(isnull($"id"))
        .select("ids")
```